# Apache JMeter: Only record POST requests with "Test Script Recorder"

Tags: jmeter

I build a JMeter test case to measure the time it takes to launch a few webservices. To do this I recorded all steps in the first attempts. Now I'm only interested in the times of the POST requests, so I want to ask, whether I can filter the POST requests out of the other steps of my recording (at recording time!)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Sorry. There is definitely no option to only record posts at the time of recording.

Answer (score 0):

Dan is right, there is no straight way to record only POST operations.

However, if you are able to characterize in some way the POST URL, you can use a proper regular expression in "Patterns to Include" in the Test Script Recorder.

At least, this can narrow down your recorded script so that you can clean it up manually afterwards.